# Set proving with multiple assumptions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A, B, C, $ and $E$ are any sets. Prove if $B\cap E = \emptyset,\: C \cup B = U, \text{ and }A \cap C = \emptyset$, then $A \cap E = \emptyset$ using by contradiction and pick-a-point method.

I've tried to solve this and here is my solution

Assumptions :
$B \cap E = \emptyset, C \cup B = U, A \cap C = \emptyset, A \cap E \neq \emptyset$

$B \cap E \subseteq \emptyset$

$x \in B$ and $x \in E$

$x \in \emptyset$ since $B \cap E \subseteq \emptyset$

$x$ is nothing since there are no elements in $\emptyset$

--

$A \cap C \subseteq \emptyset$

$y \in A$ and $y \in C$

$y \in \emptyset$ since $A \cap C \subseteq \emptyset$

$y$ is nothing since there are no elements in $\emptyset$

--

($x \in B$ and $x \in E$) and ($y \in A$ and $y \in C$)

($y \in A$ and $x \in E$) and ($y \in C$ and $y \in B$)

($y \in A$ and $x \in E$)

y and x are both null or nothing so let's just equate them to z

($z \in A$ and $z \in E$)

$z \in A \cap E$

z is null or nothing, but one of the assumptions that we made is $A \cap E \neq \emptyset$. Which is contradictory

I've been trying to solve this thing for 5 hours and I'm close to giving up haha. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is $U$ in the question?

Comment: @VivaanDaga, universal set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for contradiction that $A\cap E \neq \varnothing$. Then there exists some $x\in A\cap E$. By definition, $x\in A$ and $x\in E$. But since $B\cap E = \varnothing$ and $A\cap C = \varnothing$, it follows that $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$. Then $x\notin B\cup C$ which is impossible because $B\cup C$ is the universe, so we have reached the contradiction, as required.

Comment: @Martund These are questions where not too many approaches are available, so it is very likely solutions are similar. Let us not worry about that too much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in A\cap E$. Now, since $x\in B\cup C$, it means that $x\in B$ or $x\in C$. If $x\in B$, it means that $x\in B\cap E=\emptyset$, and if $x\in C$, it means that $x\in A\cap C=\emptyset$. So we get contradiction in both the cases.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap E)=\emptyset$$

Also, by the [distributive law for union and intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Algebraic_properties):

$$(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap E)=A\cap (C\cup B)\cap E$$

and as $C\cup B=\Omega$, we have:

$$\emptyset=(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap E)=A\cap (C\cup B)\cap E=A\cap \Omega\cap E=A\cap E$$

Therefore picking a point $x\in A\cap E$ is a contradiction, as $A\cap E=\emptyset$.

Comment: Can I ask what happened to the omega symbol in the most left hand side of the equality? Thanks!

Comment: $A\cap \Omega =A$